# Find biggest values using combination sum and max

Tags: mysql

Sample data

```
+----+------------+-------+------------+
| ID | first_name | sales | sale_date  |
+----+------------+-------+------------+
|  1 | Lindsey    | 32.02 | 2007-03-12 |
|  2 | Nicole     | 26.53 | 2007-03-12 |
|  3 | Britney    | 11.25 | 2007-03-12 |
|  4 | Ashley     | 18.96 | 2007-03-12 |
|  5 | Lindsey    |  9.16 | 2007-03-11 |
|  6 | Nicole     |  1.52 | 2007-03-11 |
|  7 | Britney    | 43.21 | 2007-03-11 |
|  8 | Ashley     |  8.05 | 2007-03-11 |
|  9 | Lindsey    | 17.62 | 2007-03-10 |
| 10 | Nicole     | 24.19 | 2007-03-10 |
| 11 | Britney    |  3.40 | 2007-03-10 |
| 12 | Ashley     | 15.21 | 2007-03-10 |
| 13 | Lindsey    |  0.00 | 2007-03-09 |
| 14 | Nicole     | 31.99 | 2007-03-09 |
+----+------------+-------+------------+
```

I try to find biggest total sales produce by any of this girl

I can find the biggest total sales by using this query

```
select first_name, sum(sales) as total 
   from cookie_sales 
   group by first_name 
   order by total desc limit 1;
```

I wonder is there a way to find same value using aggregate `max` function
If i using something like this

```
select first_name, max(sum(sales)) from cookie_sales group by first_name;
```

I will get 1111 Mysql error (Invalid use of group function )

Is there a way?

Comment: Are you trying to find the one person with the highest SUM for sales? Or trying to find the SUM of sales and the MAX sales amount for each person?

Comment: @MikeBrant person with high sum of sales

Comment: Then your first query is the way to do that.

Comment: ic, so basically no way to use `max` without using subquery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query you wrote initially in your question is probably the best approach. I don't understand what would be wrong with that.  No need to use subqueries here.

Comment: nah just wonder is there better way to do that, thanks for ur input

Answer (score 0):

You can try creating a view and then try MAX on that. Something like this:

```
CREATE VIEW sales_sums AS
select first_name, sum(sales) as total 
   from cookie_sales 
   group by first_name 
   order by total desc limit 1;


SELECT first_name, MAX(total ) AS max_total
FROM sales_sums
GROUP BY first_name
```

Comment: No need for a view when a subquery will do, and it's common to have SELECT privilege on a database, which is all that's needed for a subquery, but not CREATE privilege, which is required to `CREATE VIEW`.

Comment: No reason for a view or subquery, when the initial query written in the question is the best approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can use MAX function this way:

```
SELECT MAX(sum_sales)
FROM (
  SELECT first_name, SUM(sales) sum_sales
  FROM cookie_sales
  GROUP BY first_name
) s
```

but then if you need to get also the first_name this query will get a little more complicated than your original one.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way; you'll need to be using a MySQL version recent enough to support subqueries (should be anything 5.0 or newer):

```
SELECT first_name, MAX(total) FROM 
  (SELECT first_name, SUM(sales) AS total
   FROM cookie_sales
   GROUP BY first_name
   ORDER BY total DESC) sum_query
GROUP BY first_name
LIMIT 0, 1;
```

Comment: what happens when you remove last 2 lines from this query:
GROUP BY first_name
LIMIT 0, 1;
do you think it would still give the right answer ?

Comment: Now that I think about it, probably not; it'd probably just return the entire result of the subquery, in which case the asker's query would work just as well.

Comment: i fully aware how to use max with subqueries, i just wonder is there a way without use subquery

Comment: I agree with Mike's answer above. Also, if you remove the last 2 lines from Aaron's answer, then that would also handle the case when there are more than 1 girl with maximum total sales.